# Can't import the named export 'Children' from non EcmaScript module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am having a weird issue my react project was totally working fine for weeks!!! until this error appeard and my project is no longer working!!!  i didnt touch anything literally. i have removed packge-lock and also node_modules run npm install again but nothing changed, i also removed the latest packages that i installed that i thought they might be the prblem but im still having the same issue and i have no idea why please help.
Im not even using AnimatePresence anywhere in the code

```
./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/es/components/AnimatePresence/index.mjs
Can't import the named export 'Children' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)



{
  "name": "project-1",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@material-tailwind/react": "^2.0.1",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-react": "^4.3.0",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-helmet-async": "^1.3.0",
    "react-markdown": "^8.0.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.6.1",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build:dev": "env-cmd -f .env react-scripts start",
    "build:css": "tailwindcss build -i src/assets/tailwind.css -o src/assets/index.css --watch"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: The purpose of `package-lock. json` is to make sure that the same dependencies are installed consistently across different environments. You might have updated any of your dependencies since u have `^` in most of your dependencies which upgrades your package version to latest `minor/patch` version.. also, any of your dependency could depend on `AnimatePresence`

Answer (score 1):

According to what is written in https://github.com/framer/motion/issues/1525#issuecomment-1177081896, it seems that you need to update `react-scripts` to version 5.